# What happened if rollback table if there is no transaction?

Tags: php, eloquent, mariadb

It rare case may be but for some reason I need an outer try catch for a purpose. So I can't able to control individual transactions.

so I have just one outer catch statement.

```
catch(Exception $e) {
   DB::rollback();
   Log:error($e->getMessage());
}
```

But what happened if there is an error before any transactions hasn't initiated. Is rollback cause unexpected damage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROLLBACK` applies to a "transaction", not a "table".  There could be multiple tables involved in a transaction, or there could even be no tables *yet* involved.

`ROLLBACK` is prepared to do anything needed, even including "nothing".  Don't worry.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `DB::transactionLevel()` to get count:

```php
catch(Exception $e) {
   if (0 < DB::transactionLevel()) {
       DB::rollback();
   }
   Log:error($e->getMessage());
}
```

Reference: [Illuminate\Database\ConnectionInterface | Laravel API](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/ConnectionInterface.html#method_transactionLevel)

Comment: I'm upvoting your answer, I'm gonna use it. But it doesn't explain my question exactly